# Why complex variables used for Laplace equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

I read that, using complex numbers to solve the 2D Laplace equation proves convenient, because:

in a region where a function of the complex variables z=x+iy is analytic, the derivative with respect to z is the same in any direction.

Can someone explain what they mean by the derivative being same in any direction? And why?

Further, can anyone give me more reasons as to why the complex system is useful to solve 2D Laplace equation?

Comment: Where did you read that the derivative of an analytic complex function is the same in every direction?!?

Comment: [here](http://164.100.133.129:81/econtent/Uploads/ACD2505-04-%20Potential%20Flow-2D.pdf)

slide 6

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. The point is that complex numbers are not simply pairs of numbers, as in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The quantity $x+iy$ is a single number, rather than the pair $(x,y)$ in the plane. The derivative in the complex plane is required to exist and be independent on how $h$ is sent to 0. In $\mathbb{R}$ you have something similar: $f'$ must exists independently on how you send $h$ to 0, except that in $\mathbb{R}$ there are only two ways to send $h$ to 0 (from the left or from the right).

Comment: Complex analysis is used because holomorphic functions are necessarily harmonic. What's most useful is probably the Poisson integral, which provides a formula to the solutions of Dirichlet problems for a Laplace equation.

Comment: If you have a real harmonic function $u$ on an open simply-connected region $\Omega$ of the plane, then there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Omega$ such that $u$ is the real part of $f$. Typically it is easier to deal with holomorphic functions than with harmonic functions.

Comment: @bartgol I visited your profile and saw that you have experience in fluid dynamics, I have some questions in fluid dynamics and I have no one to approach, is there anyway I can get in contact with you please? :)

Comment: Uhm, I'm not looking forward to share my email here. I don't even know if it's allowed. Perhaps on http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Any analytic function of x+iy is a solution of Laplace’s Equation in the two dimensions spanned by x and y, so a nifty way to solve Laplace’s equation is to find an analytic function that satisfies the boundary conditions.  If you are working in three or more dimensions, then of course this method won’t work, unless the second derivative with respect to those other dimensions is zero everywhere, inherently in the problem you are solving. That of course implies that the first derivative(s) must be inherently constant.

Someone said something about fluid dynamics?  This might be appropriate for laminar flow along a straight path.